# how to perform two actions on a single click?

Tags: java, android

How can I write command in `onclicklistener()` so that I can move to next activity as well as my post status dialog will appear on that new activity. I am using `intent` for switching to next activity and also using `postTowall()` method. But these two doesn't perform simultaneously. I am using this method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    postTowall();
    Intent intent= new Intent(Frnd.this,Logout.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void postTowall() {
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

      @Override
      public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(DialogError e) {
      }

      public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
          String sh = null;
          Bundle params = new Bundle();

          params.putString("caption", sh);
      }

      public void onCancel() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
```

Comment: Add your 2 action to the listener.

Comment: Do you want show next Activity and then the Dialog? Your code is sequential, so it's impossible to make it run in  tha same time, you might use AsyncTask or Threads for this.

Comment: Paste the call (e.g. `postTowall()`) in the `onCreate()` method of the second `Activity`. Paste the code of this function in the body of the second `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use thread for posting. Use asynctask and inside that post the message to face book. Or you may just write a simple thread and start it.

This asynctask link may help you. it has usage example also:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You should set other activity to open post dialog. Send via intent a signal if it should or not...